# anime.js animation not firing on Safari (iOS7) and Opera Mini (iOS9)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, animation, anime.js

This may well be a general mobile device or iOS issue, but I'm testing on an iphone 4 and ipad Mini 1 running iOS 7 and 9 respectively.

I have a simple menu icon animation set up to expand its height when clicked (when the menu opens). The animation is fired on a click event bound to the menu div. It works perfectly on a desktop browser but does not animate on either of the mobile devices I'm testing on. This is my first shot at using the library to animate elements in my project so I'm unfamiliar with its quirks.

Can anyone give me some insight into why this is not working on mobile devices?
Could it be the fact that I have anime's function call tied to an event? or that animejs is just not compatible with the versions of those browsers I'm testing on.

here's my code (if you need more context, I'll be happy to include that, but for now I think this will suffice):

```js
var rem = function rem() {
      let html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];

      return function () {
          return parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(html)['fontSize']);
      }
  }();

 function toRem(length) {
     return (parseInt(length) / rem());
 };
  
var showTop = document.getElementById( 'showTop' ),
  nav_dot = $(".nav_dot");
  
showTop.onclick = function() {
  if (toRem(nav_dot.height()) == 0.5 ){ 

   let nav_open = anime({
     targets: '#showTop .nav_dot',
     opacity: 0.5,
     height: ['0.5rem', '4rem'],
     easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
   });
      
  } else {
   let nav_close = anime({
     targets: '#showTop .nav_dot',
     opacity: 0.7,
     height: ['4rem', '0.5rem'],
     easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
   });
  }
  };
```

```css
.nav_dots{
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: none;
  z-index: 100000;
}

.nav_dot {
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  right: 0;
  height: 0.5rem;
  width: 0.5rem;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div id="showTop" class="nav_dots element nav-trigger">
          <span class="nav_dot"></span>
          <span class="nav_dot"></span>
          <span class="nav_dot"></span>
          <span class="nav_dot"></span>
    </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>
```